# Still confused concerning using [encoding convertto...] versus chan configure when sending messages on web socket?

Tags: websocket, tcl

I asked two questions the last two days on this topic ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269418/encoding-of-web-socket-channel-and-or-encoding-convertto-messages) perhaps reasonable and the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74282879/configuring-a-channel-for-receiving-messages-on-a-web-socket-encoding-appears-t) quite stupid) but I seem to still be rather dense on this topic. I have text stored in SQLite some of which includes curly apostrophe (U-2019 &#8217). The result of the query is stored in `$result` in the code below. This is sent to the browser on web socket `$sock`.

This code results in the browser reading all the data without an error being thrown in either Tcl or the browser but does not render the curly apostrophe.

```
chan configure $sock -buffering full -blocking 0 -translation binary
set response "0 $id settle $result"
# set response [encoding convertto utf-8 "0 $id settle $result"]
set len [string length $response]
if { $len > 65535 } {
  chan puts -nonewline $sock [binary format cu2Wu {129 127} $len]
} elseif { $len > 125 } {
  chan puts -nonewline $sock [binary format cu2Su {129 126} $len]
} elseif { $len > 0 } {
  chan puts -nonewline $sock [binary format cu2 [list 129 $len]]
}
# chan configure $sock -encoding utf-8 -translation lf -eofchar {}
chan puts -nonewline $sock $response
chan flush $sock
chan configure $sock -buffering full -blocking 0 -translation binary
```

If line `set response "0 $id settle $result"` is replaced with `set response [encoding convertto utf-8 "0 $id settle $result"]`, then all the data is read and the apostrophes render. That solves my issue but I thought that I was to configure the socket rather than encoding `$result`.

If the line is not replaced but `chan configure $sock -encoding utf-8 -translation lf -eofchar {}` is inserted immediately before `chan puts -nonewline $sock $response`, an error is not thrown and the apostrophes render but all the data is not read such that part of `$response` is missing. I assume this is because `$len` is determined before it is converted to utf-8.

My questions are:

1. Is the socket supposed to be configured to utf-8 before the string is written on the channel rather than encoding `$response`? If so, how is the correct length to be determined before that and why is this preferrable to encoding `$reponse` and leaving the channel binary?
2. If the channel is supposed to be configured to utf-8, what would take place if, by chance, a new in-coming message was received on the channel after the encoding was changed to utf-8 and before it was changed back to binary after the channel is flushed to send `$response`? From experimenting, it appears that an incoming message cannot be read in Tcl unless the socket is binary.

Thank you for bearing with my thick-headedness on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be working with the websocket protocol. This is basically a binary protocol. It uses bits and bytes for command opcode, length, etc. Only some parts (text frame, close reason) contain utf-8 strings. Even those require the length to be given in bytes.

At least for sending the binary parts, the channel needs to be configured as binary. You could temporarily change the channel encoding to utf-8 to send the text parts. But you need to use an `encoding convertto utf-8` command to determine the length in bytes anyway. So it seems much easier to send the already converted data in binary mode than to keep switching the encoding and sending the original strings. But both methods will work.

When receiving a message, the channel encoding is only applied to data you read. So you would first have to set the channel to binary to read the opcode and length. Even if utf-8 text follows, you only know the length in bytes, not in characters. If you would change the channel encoding to utf-8 at that point, you couldn't read the string in one go because you don't know how much to read. So you would have to do it character by character. In binary mode, you can just read the indicated number of bytes and use `encoding convertfrom utf-8` to get the intended string.

Clearly, in a protocol like websocket, it is much easier to use binary encoding and do the utf-8 encoding and decoding of selected parts using `encoding` commands.